# Cpp including SDL library with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, sdl

Im currently trying to compile a cpp program with gcc that uses SDL2 library, and im using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Here is my folder structure

```
project
    -out
    -SDL2
    -src
        -main.cpp
```

Excluding the library i have uploaded everything to this repo https://github.com/probottpric/libtest if it gives a better understanding.

To install SDL2, I installed source code and ran `./configure` and `make all`. I dont want to run `make install` which installs it on /usr/*. I want the library to be on the local folder.

To compile program im using this command
`gcc -o ./out/main ./src/main.cpp -ISDL2 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lm -std=c++11`

But It shows library not found error. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm guessing you need `-LSDL2`

Comment: Tried this ```gcc -o ./out/main ./src/main.cpp -LSDL2 -ISDL2 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lm -std=c++11``` and still didint work :(

Comment: What OS? If Windows, what MinGW distribution? `-LSDL2` doesn't make much sense, `-L` accepts a path to a directory with `.a` files...

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. Updated it just now.

Comment: You know you can get SDL2 from the package manager? Are you building it manually for practice?

Comment: Yes, thats why I mentioned I didn't want to use ```sudo make install``` (when when used i'm able to link with -lSDL2 which works).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it does make sense if `SDL2` is a sub directory containing the libraries as is hinted at in the question. If we had a [mre] showing exactly where the libraries were then we could give the exact required arguments

Comment: Apparently the libs are in some nested directory, if it didn't work. OP, after you fix this error (by giving the right path to `-L`), make sure you have all dependencies of SDL2 installed (the list is in `docs/README-linux.md`). If you didn't have them when building SDL2, the resulting library will be barely functional (unable to open windows, etc).

Comment: I have added the library itself to the github repo. Can you check that out. Cuz i have tried same thing with asio lib, compiling it keeping it in the same directory and using ```-Iasio/include``` which worked. Tried the same thing with adding ```-ISDL2/include``` and didnt work still.

Comment: Again, you need to pass the directory with `.a`/`.so` files to `-L`. They seem to be in `SDL2/build/.libs`. Also you don't need `-lSDL2main`, it's Windows-only.

Comment: So I tried this ```gcc -o ./out/main ./src/main.cpp -LSDL2/build/.libs -lSDL2 -m64 -lstdc++ -std=c++11```. Still nothing...

Comment: Remove `-m64` and `-lstdc++`, replace `gcc` with `g++`. Can you add the exact error you get?

Comment: Running ```g++ -o ./out/main ./src/main.cpp -LSDL2/build/.libs -std=c++11``` gives ```./src/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory                        
    3 | #include <SDL2/SDL.h>                                                                  
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                  
compilation terminated.```

Comment: *"It shows library not found error"* It says it can't find a header, not a library. :/ That's why you always need to add the errors to the question from the very beginning. `-I` needs a path to the directory where the directory `SDL2` (with `SDL.h` in it) is located. Remove `-ISDL2` and replace it with the right path.

Comment: But still using ```g++ -o ./out/main ./src/main.cpp -ISDL2/include -LSDL2/build/.libs -lSDL2 -std=c++11``` give that same error

Comment: Please carefully read my previous comment. `SDL2/include` contains `SDL.h` directly. But since you include `SDL2/SDL.h` rather than `SDL.h`, the path you give to `-I` must contain not `SDL.h`, but a directory called `SDL2` with `SDL.h` in it.

Comment: Dammm... i was having a very big misunderstanding. It didnt even strike me that 'SDL2/SDL.h' was like a directory path. I was thinking like -I 'SDL2' or 'SDL.h'. Now it works (i changed main.cpp like #include <SDL.h>). Thanks  LOT :D

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer. Do not edit the question to say that it is solved

Comment: Why don't you do `configure --prefix="XXX"` so that it gets installed in directory XXX when you do `make install`?

Comment: Also, SDL2 provides a program that will give you all the flags and switches and libraries you need to compile, try `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` That enables you to compile with `gcc program.c $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs) -o program`